# Negative patterns are ignored in git attributes

Tags: git, clone

when I clone a remote url,this happends,how can I fix this,help

[image]

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your `.gitignore` together with the command. Please post it as *code*, not as a *image* of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is clear : `Negative patterns are ignored in git attributes`.

The [gitattributes doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) says:

> Unlike `.gitignore`, negative patterns are forbidden.

So the way to fix it is one of:

- change the `.gitattributes` content to not try to use negative pattern
- escape the exclamation point with '!' as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Git explains in the message how to fix the issue. It doesn't tell very clear what the problem is but from the message I suppose your `.gitattributes` contains a line that starts with `!`.

The documentation of [`.gitattributes`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) mentions:

> The rules how the pattern matches paths are the same as in `.gitignore` files; see [`gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore). Unlike `.gitignore`, negative patterns are forbidden.

If you have a file whose name starts with `!` then use `\!` instead in `.gitattributes`.

Otherwise remove the `!`, **it doesn't** tell Git to exclude the file that follows it from a rule mentioned above in the file as it happens in `.gitignore` and this is what Git is trying to tell in the warning message.